# Ansible install packages on target without network con

Tags: vpn, ansible

Is there any way to use ( for egg. when installing a yum package ) the ansible-controller network connection to the internet?

Comment: You can download packages on the controller, upload them to the target and install them "manually" from there. It's ok for a very small set of packages. If you have to multiply this, it's probably a better idea to install a repository manager like nexus or artifactory to proxy outside repos.

Comment: thanks, but I connected targets to the internet, was the easiest way :)

Answer (score 0):

Not a good way. Ansible's connection is for running its tasks, and is torn down after it is done. Better ways exist to set up a persistent tunnel.

Consider local mirrors to install software to hosts without Internet. Create and maintain yum repos or whatever other software set you need.

Comment: I'm thinking that somehow you can download yum packages through your controller network ... :)